# How to check if an hash is "completely" included in another hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, methods, hash

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to check if an hash is "completely" included in another hash and return a *boolean* value.

Say I have those hashes:

```
hash1 = {
  :key1 => 'value1',
  :key2 => 'value2',
  :key3 => 'value3'
}

hash2 = {
  :key1 => 'value1',
  :key2 => 'value2',
  :key3 => 'value3',
  :key4 => 'value4',
  :key5 => 'value5',
  ...
}
```

I would like to check if the `hash1` is included in the `hash2` even if in the `hash2` there are more values than `hash1` (in the above case the response that I am looking for should be `true`)? **Is it possible to do that *by using "one only code line"\"a Ruby method"*?**

Comment: Perhaps you can merge hash1 into hash2 (`hash2.merge(hash1)`) and see if it changed. That's a very naive way of doing it, but if it's one line of code you want, it's probably the simplest way.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That will be enough

```
(hash1.to_a - hash2.to_a).empty?
```

Comment: Nice. That's why I added the "I can think of" part to my answer ;-)

Comment: Brilliant! I just spent an hour playing with **collect** **include?** **values_at** and friends... with no reasonable result. To finally hit this answer. So simple.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way I can think of would be:

```
hash2.values_at(*hash1.keys) == hash1.values
```

Answer (score 5):

the more elegant way is to check the equality when one hash merge another.

e.g. rewrite Hash include? instance method for this.

```
class Hash
  def include?(other)
    self.merge(other) == self
  end
end

{:a => 1, :b => 2, :c => 3}.include? :a => 1, :b => 2 # => true
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a way:

```
hash_2 >= hash_1
```

Alternatively:

```
hash_1 <= hash_2
```

More info in this post: https://olivierlacan.com/posts/proposal-for-a-better-ruby-hash-include/

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and elegant solution I've found - with no intermediary arrays, or redundant loops.

```rb
class Hash
  alias_method :include_key?, :include?

  def include?(other)
    return include_key?(other) unless other.is_a?(Hash)
    other.all? do |key, value|
      self[key] == value
    end
  end
end
```

---

Since Ruby 2.3 you can use built-in [`Hash#<=`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-3C) method.

Answer (score 1):

Since [Ruby 2.3](https://olivierlacan.com/posts/hash-comparison-in-ruby-2-3/), you can do this:

```rb
hash1 <= hash2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the inclusion idea in hash. 
To see if it has the same keys(usual problem).
All keys in hash1 are included in hash2:
hash1.keys - hash2.keys == []

Then if you want to compare those values do as suggested in the previous post:
hash1.values - hash2.values_at(*hash1.keys) == []